# good example for grails using atmosphere plugin

Tags: grails, atmosphere

I am looking for a good example or tutorial which deals with grails and the atmosphere plugin.
The tutorials i found seems like to miss some information to get my examples working.

thanks

Comment: Note that atmosphere is not licensed using the MIT license... that's why I use cometd-plugin for asynchronous server push. Unfortunately it is more bad documented, however the concept is more clean than of atmosphere plugin.

Comment: @crudolf - Why is the [Apache 2.0 license](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/blob/master/LICENSE-2.0.txt) a problem?  It's the same license used by [Grails and all Grails plugins](http://grails.org/License).

Comment: yes, apache 2.0 license fits fine for my aims

Comment: sorry, it looks like the latest version (0.4) has changed license from GPL to ASF. good to know then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i found something i was looking for. Here you can get a working project with atmosphere used in grails: https://github.com/rbramley/GroovyMagJMS

Comment: It's BuildConfig file doesn't contain entry for atmosphere plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look here?

http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/

Also try asking in the mailing list:

http://groups.google.com/group/atmosphere-framework/

Comment: Thanks for the links but they doesn't contain any gui-side examples